# Can I use Azure api management for gRPC communication?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, grpc, azure-api-management

I would like to place APIM between communications in gRPC.
Is this possible?

Comment: If you haven't seen anything in Azure's documentation about it, probably not.

Comment: yeah, I cant look for gRPC`s docs in Azure`s docs....

Comment: From November 2023 in Public Preview: https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/updates/public-preview-support-for-grpc-apis-in-azure-api-management-selfhosted-gateway/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [gunr2171](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1043380/gunr2171), if it's not documented then as of now it's not possible.

You can refer to this [feature request/feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/94c91545-0225-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0858) related to supporting gRPC in Azure API Management.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, it's possible to use gRPC with APIM, the announcement was for Nov 2023 here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/introducing-grpc-api-support-in-azure-api-management-self-hosted/ba-p/3975087

So when you want to add new API you can choose gRPC:

[image]

By uploading `.proto` file, the APIM able to use gRPC service:

[image]